# How do I look up man page references with square brackets?

Tags: command-line, manpage, info

Sometimes man pages contain references to other information pages, for example **Everyday Git**[1] and **gittutorial**(7) are referred to in the man page for **git**. Those with round bracketed numbers refer to other man pages, so for the gittutorial man page I enter:

```
 man 7 gittutorial
```

How do I access the info referred to in square brackets? (eg: **Everyday Git**[1])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The references in square brackets on the `git` man page seem to be referencing footnotes from the same page rather than being references to other man page.  From the bottom of the `git` man page:

```
NOTES
    1. Everyday Git
       file:///usr/share/doc/git-doc/everyday.html
```

Comment: Yep, I'd say your'e right. All 10 of the NOTES listed are referred to earlier in the man page with appropriate number in square brackets. Thanks.