# How do I look up man page references with round brackets?

Tags: manpage

I have seen [How do I look up man page references with square brackets?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75336/25656). The questioner gives the example of `gittutorial(7)` and being able to access it by `man 7 gittutorial`.

When I look at `man regex`, the top line has:

```
REGEX(7)                   Linux Programmer's Manual                  REGEX(7)
```

Now this man page is too difficult for me, so when I see:

```
AUTHOR
       This page was taken from Henry Spencer's regex package.

SEE ALSO
       grep(1), regex(3)

       POSIX.2, section 2.8 (Regular Expression Notation).
```

I try `man 3 regex` but that gives me:

```
[06:46 PM] ~ $ man 3 regex
No manual entry for regex in section 3
[06:46 PM] ~ $
```

What is the correct way to access `regex(3)`?

`man 7 regex` works for `regex(7)`, `man 4 tty` works for `tty(4)` and `man 8 updatedb` works for `updatedb(8)`.

Comment: Do you have the `manpages-posix-dev` package installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manpage of `regex` in section 3 in not present on your system.

To find out which package this file contains type use `apt-file`. You need to install it first and then update the local cache:

```
user@host:~# apt-get install apt-file
user@host:~# apt-file update
```

Then search the cache with:

```
user@host:~# apt-file search /usr/share/man/man3/regex.3.gz
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/regex.3.gz
```

So you see which packages you can install: `manpages-dev`:

```
user@host:~# apt-get install manpages-dev
```

After installation `man 3 regex` should work.

Comment: I do have `/usr/share/man/man3` with quite a few .gz files in there. But `regex.3.gz` isn't there as you point out. I'm not keen on installing it. There are easier reads on `regex` available but now I know why I don't have `regex(3)` :)

Comment: Yeah google man 3 regex and you're in, but I thought it's better to know how to get them or find out where they are... =)

Answer (score 0):

"man 3 regex" is the correct command and it works fine for me. Probably, you don't have installed the necessary packages that provide the manpage.
Visit this [page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12702/no-manual-page-for-regex-in-section-3-where-is-it) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the U&L link! [I guess this is because they take up about 20 MB, and some users don't need them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12707/15760) makes sense.